# rmdir/unlink not working through cron

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I wrote a cron job that will delete folders (and files inside of it) with dates older than `today - 14 days` using `DateTime`.

On my server, if I browse to the file (cleanup.php) in my web browser, it deletes the folders and files fine.

The cron job runs because I get the first `mail`. I am thinking this is a permissions thing? Can anyone advise?

The CRON command being ran:

`php /home/myUserName/public_html/file-transfer/uploads/cleanup.php`

```
<?php
mail('myEmail@gmail.com','cron bon', 'cleanup starting');

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$ignore = array(
  '.',
  '..',
  '.htaccess',
  'cleanup.php'
);

function rrmdir($dir)
{
  if (is_dir($dir))
  {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object)
    {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..")
      {
        if (filetype($dir . "/" . $object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir . "/" . $object); else unlink($dir . "/" . $object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
}

$today = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', date('m-d-Y', strtotime('today')));
$dirs = scandir('./');

foreach ($dirs as $dir)
{
  if (!in_array($dir, $ignore))
  {
    $dirDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $dir);
    $interval = $dirDate->diff($today);

    if ($interval->format('%r%a') > 14)
    {
      rrmdir($dir);
    }
  }
}

mail('myEmail@gmail.com','cron bon', 'cleanup has ran');
?>
```

I don't know how to debug this since cron is starting it

**EDIT**

@SuperJer was originally correct in the issue being related to `./` I have updated my code and this is working as a cron job now.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$ignore = array(
  '.',
  '..',
  '.htaccess',
  'cleanup.php'
);

$fullPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/'; //-- Added this line and added it to my rrmdir function

function rrmdir($dir)
{
  if (is_dir($dir))
  {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object)
    {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..")
      {
        if (filetype($dir . "/" . $object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir . "/" . $object); else unlink($dir . "/" . $object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
}

$today  = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', date('m-d-Y', strtotime('today')));
$dirs   = scandir($fullPath);
$msg    = '';

foreach ($dirs as $dir)
{
  if (!in_array($dir, $ignore))
  {
    $dirDate  = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $dir);
    $interval = $dirDate->diff($today);
    if ($interval->format('%r%a') > 14) rrmdir($fullPath . $dir);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: you can start it own your own @*I don't know how to debug* by using shell or any equal function in php

Comment: `.htaccess` style files are irrelevant here, since you access the script per cli, not per http.

Comment: Under which user account is that script started? This could well be a simple file permission issue.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by 'If I browse to the file'.  Are you browsing to it in the command line and executing it there or via a web browser?  Also, what distro are you using?  Different distros use different means of specifying which system 'user' executes a given command in cron, thereby affecting permissions for the script.

Comment: ok, I'll remove the comment about htaccess. @SuperJer Browse to it in a web browser. I dont know what distro I am using. It's not my server. How can I check? They're using cpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue may be the difference between the way php resolves file paths when running under apache and under the command line (or cron).

If your application allows, instead of using `./`, use the full path, such as `/home/myUserName/public_html/file-transfer/uploads/`

You can also use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the full system path to the current running script, which will allow this to be a little more portable.

Additionally, this difference also affects `include` and `require` paths.

Comment: Ah, full system path. I will give this a shot and report back

Comment: bummer, still didn't work. It worked locally on my dev machine, but not as a cron. I tried both pathname and `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Then it sounds like it is in fact a permissions issue.  I would look through your documentation with your hosting company and maybe contact them to determine the best course of action.  You may want to increase/enable the error reporting for the script as well, so that your cron responses report any additional relevant data.

Comment: It may also be possible that you need to call the php binary by it's full path in the cron job.  Such as `/usr/bin/php` or `/usr/local/bin/php`, though I expect this would have been indicated by your cron emails.

Comment: ok so I tried something a little different. I made a file called test.php in my uploads dir and all it has in it is `shell_exec('php /home/myUserName/public_html/file-transfer/uploads/cleanup.php');` when I execute it through hitting test.php in the web browser, it deletes the folders, however, an error_log is generated with this `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function diff() on a non-object` which is pointing at the `$interval` line. It may be unrelated and seems kind of hacky running shell twice

Comment: So it appears your `DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $dir);` is failing, causing the script to halt.  Perhaps put in a condition to check to make sure your `$dirDate` is a valid object before executing its `->diff()`.  Looks like you have a means of debugging now.  I expect once you have it running without errors, your cron job will function as advertised.

Comment: well, I feel dumb. I managed to get the script to email me what directories it was scanning and I believe your original answer is the right answer. I missed one sport for the path so its looking at all the system files. Let me get back to you again

Comment: You sir, were correct in it being a path issue! I'm going to post what my code looks like now in my question above